# Sum all rows in a column function using google app scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column `"Net Sales"` and I am trying to sum all the values in that column in google sheets but using google app scripts. The data for Net Sales will change so I am trying to be as abstract as possible. Here is the function I have so far, the output of the total sum is shown in a separate spreadsheet. Instead of actually adding up all of the sales, this function just puts all the numbers together. For example, if the rows in column Net Sales are 100, 200, and 50, the output would be 10020050 instead of 350. How do I get a function to actually add the numbers together?

---

```
//sum of all net sales (not working)
var netSquare = sheet_origin2.getRange(2, 12, sheet_origin2.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<=sheet_origin2.getLastRow(); i++) {
    sum += netSquare[i];
  }
  sheet_destination.getRange(sheet_destination.getLastRow(), 2, 1, 1).setValue(sum);
```

---

Answer (score 1):

1. The last row ≠ the number of rows, especially since you're skipping the first row.
2. [`.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a 2-d array, so you need to use `netSquare[i][0]`
3. You should use the length of the array you're iterating over in your for-loop and also be sure that your index doesn't go out-of-bounds.

```
function sum() {
  // ... define the sheets ...
  var lastRow = sheet_origin2.getLastRow();
  var numRows = lastRow - 1; // Subtract one since you're skipping the first row
  var netSquare = sheet_origin2.getRange(2, 12, numRows, 1).getValues();
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<netSquare.length; i++) {
    sum += netSquare[i][0];
  }
  sheet_destination.getRange(sheet_destination.getLastRow(), 2, 1, 1).setValue(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### A way more efficient way to calculate the sum is to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and in this way you get rid of `for` loops.

The sum can be calculated with just the `reduce` function. All the other functions: `flat`, `map`, `filter` are used to make sure the data is correct since we don't know how your spreadsheet file is constructed and what are the values you are using. See the code comments for detailed explanation of every step.

### Solution:

```
const netSquare = sheet_origin2.getRange('L2:L').getValues(). // get column L (12th column)
                    flat(). // convert the 2D array to 1D array
                    filter(v=>v!=''). // filter out empty cells
                    map(v=>parseInt(v)); // convert string numbers to integers
const sum = netSquare.reduce((a,b)=>a+b); // add all numbers together
sheet_destination.getRange(sheet_destination.getLastRow(), 2, 1, 1).setValue(sum);
```

Comment: I have seen Cooper commenting reduce on the question but it seems it was deleted. It's good seeing it being explained as an answer. +1

Comment: I commented it. :P but then used it as an answer. But glad you liked it. @NaziA

Comment: My bad :D. I frequently see his name and I also opened a lot of posts earlier. I may have mistakenly remember his name on this one.

Comment: Is calling flat, filter, map, and then reduce actually more efficient than a single iteration?

Comment: Flat filter and map might be optional and irrelevant to the calculation of the sum. Since we don't have a picture of the sheet we don't know if getlastrow returns the correct number or not ( I use filter to make sure this does not affect the solution). Furthermore, he might be using string values therefore I am using map to convert them to integers. Flat can also be omitted but you will have to use an index and personally I find it confusing. Long story short, sum can be calculated with just the reduce function. All the other functions are used to make sure the data is correct. @Diego

Comment: @Diego i found this somewhere and often find that in large scale data, filter, map, reduce and similar functions are less efficient than loops. We just think of it as our last resort. Please see performance analysis on JS for loops vs reduce and similar functions.

https://awesomeopensource.com/project/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS

Answer (score 0):

The shortest fix for this one would be to type cast since they became string when you fetched the data.

change your:

```
 sum += netSquare[i];
```

to:

```
 sum += parseInt(netSquare[i]); // if whole number
 sum += parseFloat(netSquare[i]); // if number has decimal
```

This forces the `netSquare[i]` value to be in type integer/float which can be added as numbers.
There will no be issues when we are sure that netSquare[i] values are all numbers.

For the possible issues, you can check possible [outcomes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parseint) when type casting a non-number data.

Comment: After trying this, I got the value #NUM!

Comment: @maggie, can you show some sample data you are trying to add here? if we just add numbers, that shouldn't be the case. if we are adding cells that has non-number data, it could be the issue.

are these numbers exponents? having letters in the cells?

Comment: All the data in that column are in USD format ($100.00) do you think this is the issue?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, added dollar notation on my test column and it still works. Diego has some insights in your issue, you might want to check that out.