# Add a button to copy a range of cells and add them to the value of another range of cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to create a button that will copy a range of cells, and add the numbers in those cells to the value of a duplicate range elsewhere in the workbook.

Specifically, RPing a tavern in a videogame and would like to log how many drinks of each type are sold. I want to be able to populate column B in the shown image with numbers, and then when the formula in columns C and D has resolved, I can press the red cell, blank the entries in column B, and have their values added to a "Total drinks sold tonight" ledger elsewhere on the worksheet.

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnFyq.png)

I'm looking for advice tbh. I tried looking at the initial tutorials for scripting and trying a few of the lessons, which are helping me to understand the fundamentals, but I'm wondering if you guys can help me with the response, and I can learn 'backwards' from that.

I guess though, that eventually I'll be able to do this myself if I persist ^^

Comment: You need to know what you are using: Excel macros won't work in Googlesheets.

Comment: Google Sheets is not Excel, and Excel VBA does not work in Google Sheets. Make up your mind which one you're using, and then [edit] your question accordingly. I've removed the Excel-related tags and added one for Google Sheets, because that's what you had put in your post title. Please use only tags that are actually applicable to your question - tags here have relevance and meaning, and should be used properly.

Comment: Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: You've asked for advice: 1) forget macros, write a script. 2) read [Sum all rows in a column function using google app scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993542/1330560)1) - sums a range and puts the total into another cell. 3) read [Update google script to clear a specific range of cells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61019556/1330560); don't use the red cell as a trigger, use a button - read [How to create a button in Google Sheets?](https://spreadsheet.dev/buttons-in-google-sheets). Turn that into a script and let us know what problems you have.

Comment: @Tedinoz, thanks! I'll check those out and get back to you!

The rest, edits made. LMAO I should post a meme I saw recently about StackOverflow responses, it was far truer than I expected!

Answer (score 1):

You want a way to add up the quantity of drinks in a table, put the value into a given cell, and clear the individuals drinks quantities.

Try this script together with a button.

---

```
function sumDrinkOrders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName) 

  // get the drink orders range
  var drinkOrdersRange = sheet.getRange("B4:B14")
  var drinkOrders = drinkOrdersRange.getValues()
  Logger.log(drinkOrders)

  // add up the drink orders
  var data  = drinkOrders.flat().filter(Number); // skip empty cells and non-didgits
  var sum   = data.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
  Logger.log(sum)

  // copy the total orders to the total range
  var totalRange = sheet.getRange("B2")
  totalRange.setValue(sum) 
  
  // clear the orders
  drinkOrdersRange.clearContent()
}
```

---

**SAMPLE - BEFORE**

[image: before]

---

**SAMPLE - AFTER**

[image: after]